# Llamado a funcion con parametro array entero en query nativo spring boot

Tags: java, api, postgresql, spring

Este es el query en spring

```java
 @Query(value="SELECT  * FROM FnInfoEmpleados(?1);", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer getInfoEmpleados(List<Integer> aEmpleados);
```

Me lanza el error:

```
 [/api/info?aEmpleados=[%2797597287,97597290%27] ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

Cuando lo pruebo en postman asi

```
http://localhost:8081/api/info?aEmpleados=[97597287,97597290]
```

En postgeSQL la función la llamo así:

```sql
SELECT  * FROM FnInfoEmpleados('{97597252,97597242,97597243,97597244,97597255,97597246,97597247}');
```

Pueden decirme que esta mal

Comment: Tienes que agregar esto al archivo de propiedades: `server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=|,{,},[,]` o, si usas yaml: `server: tomcat: relaxed-query-chars: '|,{,},[,]'` así te aceptará caracteres como `{` `}`.